# Not able to invoke device method

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I am getting below exception while invoking device method  using service client.
Method name -

```
InvokeDeviceMethodAsync(String, CloudToDeviceMethod)
```

Exception -

```
{"Message":"{\"errorCode\":400004,\"trackingId\":\"75ba4e76e11a46e3b68bf4de8faa8b00-G:16-TimeStamp:10/18/2019 09:13:54\",\"message\":\"methodName is null or empty.\",\"timestampUtc\":\"2019-10-18T09:13:54.7546319Z\"}","ExceptionMessage":""}
```

Version -

```
Microsoft.Azure.Devices 1.18.1
```

I am using this in azure function and wasted time to investigate this issue. 
Any help from community is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you read an error message?

Comment: Do you want to send an async message to the device or to invoke a device method in the sync manner?

Comment: @Roman kiss sorry it was my bad it's device method.

Comment: What is the method name? The error message said, that the method name is *null* or *empty*.

Comment: If I send invoke device method using device explorer it gets called and receiving 200

Comment: The Device Explorer (or portal) requires to populate the Method Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue..
Method name parameter of CloudToDeviceMethod object becomes lower case in json  when we pass to

```
InvokeDeviceMethodAsync(String, CloudToDeviceMethod)
```

iot hub cannot resolve that method name field of json and gives this error.